# How to find all unique matches between two vectors?

Tags: r, tidyr, combinatorics

I have two sets, and each element of one set can match with any element of the
other set. For example, if I have sets {1, 2, 3} and {4, 5, 6}, the possible
combinations are:

1, 4
2, 5
3, 6

1, 4
2, 6
3, 5

1, 5
2, 4
3, 6

1, 5
2, 6
3, 4

1, 6
2, 4
3, 5

1, 6
2, 5
3, 4

So when matching the two sets, there are 6 possible ways the 2 sets can be
combined. Is there a way to determine all possible set combinations given two
arbitrary vectors?

I’ve tried using `tidyr::expand_grid()`, but this gives all possible
combinations of the two vectors without the constraint that each element can
be matched with only one element from the other vector in any given set.

```r
tidyr::expand_grid(set1 = c(1, 2, 3), set2 = c(4, 5, 6))
#> # A tibble: 9 × 2
#>    set1  set2
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     4
#> 2     1     5
#> 3     1     6
#> 4     2     4
#> 5     2     5
#> 6     2     6
#> 7     3     4
#> 8     3     5
#> 9     3     6
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can fix the position of one vector, but enumerate all permutations of the other one and bind them to the previously fixed vector, such that you won't obtain *isomorsphism* among all combinations, e.g.,

```
> library(pracma)

> Map(cbind, list(v1), asplit(perms(v2), 1))
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    6
[2,]    2    5
[3,]    3    4

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    6
[2,]    2    4
[3,]    3    5

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    5
[2,]    2    6
[3,]    3    4

[[4]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    5
[2,]    2    4
[3,]    3    6

[[5]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    4
[2,]    2    5
[3,]    3    6

[[6]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    4
[2,]    2    6
[3,]    3    5
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `RcppAlgos::permuteGeneral` to apply a `FUN`ction that `cbind`s each permutation of `v2` to `v1`.

```
RcppAlgos::permuteGeneral(v=v2, m=3, FUN=\(x) cbind(X1=v1, X2=x))
# [[1]]
#      X1 X2
# [1,]  1  4
# [2,]  2  5
# [3,]  3  6
# 
# [[2]]
#      X1 X2
# [1,]  1  4
# [2,]  2  6
# [3,]  3  5
# 
# [[3]]
#      X1 X2
# [1,]  1  5
# [2,]  2  4
# [3,]  3  6
# 
# [[4]]
#      X1 X2
# [1,]  1  5
# [2,]  2  6
# [3,]  3  4
# 
# [[5]]
#      X1 X2
# [1,]  1  6
# [2,]  2  4
# [3,]  3  5
# 
# [[6]]
#      X1 X2
# [1,]  1  6
# [2,]  2  5
# [3,]  3  4
```

---

*Data:*

```
v1 <- 1:3
v2 <- 4:6
```